# get a string between a tag (TEST in <div><p>p1</p>TEST<p>p2</p></div>)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

***Code:***

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div><p>p1</p>TEST<p>p2</p></div>')
print soup.div()
```

***Result:***

```
[<p>p1</p>, <p>p2</p>]
```

How come the string `TEST` isn't in the result set? How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.div()` is a shortcut for `soup.div.find_all()` which would [find you all](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) **tags** inside the `div` tag - as you can see, it does the job. `TEST` is a text between the `p` tags, or, in other words, the `tail` of the first `p` tag.

You can get the `TEST` string by getting the first `p` tag and using [`.next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
>>> soup.div.p.next_sibling
u'TEST'
```

Or, by getting the second element of the `div`'s [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
>>> soup.div.contents[1]
u'TEST'
```

Answer (score 0):

from bs4

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div><p>p1</p>TEST<p>p2</p></div>')
print soup.div.text
u'p1TESTp2'
```